# Setting third-level folder permissions without Azure P1 license

Tags: powershell, power-automate

Can you help us with setting up permissions for a third level sub folder while keeping everything above it as read-only? Our current flow only allows for second level permissions to be set upon file creation, but we need to ensure that any folders created within the second level have the appropriate third level permissions. Additionally, we are limited by not having an Azure P1 license and being on a free Azure subscription.